# R agrep: how to match with more than 1 substitution

Tags: regex, r, agrep

I'm trying to match a string to a vector of strings:

```
a <- c('abcde', 'abcdf', 'abcdg')

agrep('abcdh', a, max.distance=list(substitutions=1))
# [1] 1 2 3

agrep('abchh', a, max.distance=list(substitutions=2))
# character(0)
```

I didn't expect the latter result as substituting two characters from 
the pattern makes the pattern identical to the vector elements.  This does, however, work with `all` instead of `substitutions`:

```
agrep('abchh', a, max.distance=list(all=2))
# [1] 1 2 3
```

What do I need to change to match with more than 1 substitution allowed?  Is `substitution` just a broken option?  Thanks.

Note: this question is essentially the same as this one: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-June/281731.html, but that was never answered.

Comment: If you want to only allow substitions, you could use `all=2, insertions=0, deletions=0, substitions=2`. I can't explain the behaviour other than to add that for, your example, it disappears when the string length is greater than 10, so might be linked to `If cost is not given, all defaults to 10%` (from `?agrep`)

Comment: Hmm, for me it did not disappear even when I used very long strings.  It does seem a little buggy, like it's overriding itself.  But good idea for a workaround, thanks!

Comment: For the sake of using the same comparison, I was comparing `agrep("abchh", "abcdd", max.distance=list(substitutions=2))` to `agrep("aaaaaaabchh", "aaaaaaabcdd", max.distance=list(substitutions=2))
`

Comment: I tried this and noted that integer(0) came back, but also the difference between .2 and .21                                      > agrep('abchh', a, max.distance=0.21)
[1] 1 2 3
> agrep('abchh', a, max.distance=0.2)
integer(0)

Answer (score 1):

I did not realize that the questions were that old, anyway:

The function needs `cost` to be appropiate. As *ping* said, you must set the maximum number of match cost; in your example:

```
a <- c('abcde', 'abcdf', 'abcdg')
agrep('abcdh', a, max.distance = list(cost = 1))
[1] 1 2 3
agrep('abchh', a, max.distance = 2)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Now, if you set `cost` the program can do insertions, deletions and substitutions. If you want only evaluate substitutions, then:

```
agrep('abhhh', a, 
        max.distance=list(cost=3, substitutions=3, 
                          deletions=0, insertions=0))
[1] 1 2 3
```